# I need some help my pictures aren't showing up on this site i'm making

Tags: html, image

I'm having trouble with getting the images to show up on the site and i need some help. This is the code without the css code in. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. heres the link to the first image:[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304.*CB286975940*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg). If anyone could help me out with the first one I would be really grateful of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head> 
<body>

    <h1>  I thought the traditional way was a little boring so I made this. </h1>
    <h2> I added some of your favorite things to this site. </h2>
    <h3> </h3>

    <img scr="Cats.jpg" style="width:592;height:304;">  
    <br>
    <br>
    <img scr="P!ATD.jpg" style="width:400;height:400;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <img scr="MCR.jpg" style="width:450;height:450;">


    <p> Alexis </p>
    <p> Would you give me the honor in taking you to prom??? </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `src` attribute (not scr, misspelled) and you should specify a unit on width/height (likely `px` for pixels).

`<img scr="Cats.jpg" style="width:592;height:304;">`

instead:

`<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg" style="width:592px;height:304px;">`

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code:

```
<img scr="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304.CB286975940.jpg" style="width:592;height:304;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg" style="width:592px; height:304px;" />
```

For the first image